Adding OAuth scopes to a call in an OpenApi Generator generated client
I'm using OpenAPI Generator (7.8.0-SNAPSHOT with RestSharp library) to generate a C# client for a rest api deployed on Azure that is using OAuth to grant access and authorizations.
Now the configuration object to be passed on the api class constructor, allows me to specify some OAuth parameters:
Configuration c = new Configuration();
c.BasePath = myOptions.BaseUrl;
c.OAuthClientId = myOptions.ClientId;
c.OAuthClientSecret = myOptions.ClientSecret;
c.OAuthTokenUrl = myOptions.Authority.TrimEnd('/') + "/oauth2/v2.0/token";
c.OAuthFlow = Client.Auth.OAuthFlow.APPLICATION;
            
MyApi apiInstance = new MyApi(c);

var result = await apiInstance.MyPostWithHttpInfoAsync(myObject);

But I cannot find a way to specify the "scope" associated with the resource of the api I want to call.
And this is needed for a correct authorization on Azure side.
Is there a way to specify this value?
Are there any differences when using other libraries (e.g. generichost, httpclient)?
Does the generated client manage the token refresh also?

Scope has been added last week: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/19234 . I don't know about your other questions though.

I've switched to version 7.8.0 after reply from @gebi but I cannot find the scope property. Actually, now the Configuration class doesn't contain any of the previous existing OAuth* fields. Where are they? Am I missing something?
